# Function returning results twice

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm using Wordpress and built a custom post type to return a list of options from a comma separated list in the post, then create a set of checkboxes in a contact form 7 form. The function is working but for some reason it's returning the output twice. I'm trying to figure out how to make it just return once.

```
wpcf7_add_shortcode('cargooptions', 'createbox', true);
function createbox(){

    global $post;

    $model = $_GET['mz'];


$args = array(
'post_type' => 'options',
'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Opts_category',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => strtolower($model)

    ),  
),

);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );


foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);


        $options = explode(',', get_the_content());

        // output list
        foreach ($options as $key => $value){

            $output .= '<input type="checkbox" name="option_'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" id="opt'.$key.'" class="optionSelect">';
            $output .= '<label for="opt'.$key.'"  class="span_4 colWrap"><span></span> ' . trim($value) . '</label>';
        }

    endforeach;
return $output;
```

Comment: If you `var_dump` output at the end of your function, what does it output?

Comment: You should get an error with this code; So since you don't say anything about this you probably have error reporting off...

Comment: Can you tell me why this would cause an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below code. 
You need to instantiate the `$output` variable before the loop, else it will append to itself on the main loop.

```
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);


        $options = explode(',', get_the_content());

        // output list
        $output = ''; // add this here so it doesn't append to itself
        foreach ($options as $key => $value){

            $output .= '<input type="checkbox" name="option_'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" id="opt'.$key.'" class="optionSelect">';
            $output .= '<label for="opt'.$key.'"  class="span_4 colWrap"><span></span> ' . trim($value) . '</label>';
        }

    endforeach;
return $output;
```